# Parse phrase with indexof and then get beginning of word

Tags: java, string, indexof

I have a phrase and a keyword. I'm trying to find the first indexof the keyword, but then get the whole word containing it. How do I get the whole word? The problem is the keyword might be text within the a word.

Example

```
String keyword = "wor";

String phrase = "my keyword search phrase";
```

I'd like to return `"keyword search phrase"`

I tried `phrase.indexOf(keyword);`

but I naturally get `"word search phrase"`

Comment: Can u explain a bit more clear?

Comment: Are you allowed to use regular expressions or are you limited to using `indexOf`?

Comment: What ever is most efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `phrase.indexOf(keyword)` and backtrack to the last space before it:

```
String keyword = "wor";
String phrase = "my keyword search phrase";
int keywordIndex = phrase.indexOf(keyword);
int lastSpaceIndex = phrase.substring(0, keywordIndex).lastIndexOf(' ');
return phrase.substring(lastSpaceIndex + 1);
```

Comment: Which Java you're using? Because the line `phrase.lastIndexOf(' ', phrase.substring(0, keywordIndex));` doesn't work with Java 7. There is no method `lastIndexOf(char, String)`.

Comment: @Tom got two lines of thought confused. Edited and fixed - thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String keyword = "wor";
String phrase = "my keyword search phrase";
int keywordsIndex = phrase.indexOf(keyword);
int spaceIndex = phrase.substring(0, keywordsIndex).lastIndexOf(' ');
System.out.println (phrase.substring(spaceIndex + 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer regular expressions, because then you can check for a word even if it was separated by something other than a space, like a tab character.

```
    String keyword = "wor";

    String phrase = "my keyword search phrase\twor";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + keyword + "\\b");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(phrase);

    int i = 0;
    if ( m.find()) {
        i = m.start();
    }
```